# Creating a valid hyperlink inside another that used <a> element

Tags: jquery, html

quick jQuery question

I'm using an `<a>` element to open a lightbox. This element is actually the thumbnail, when hovering over the thumbnail the user can see text.

I'm dynamically adding the text from inside the lightbox as hover text for the thumbnail. That's why it's important for me to use hyperlink inside this `<p>`element.

```
<a href="#modal" class="element">
  <div class="elementOver">
    <h3><strong>Titel</strong></h3>
    <p> <a href="#">LINK GOED HERE</a> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="elementCon">
    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="BG">
  </div>
</a>
```

Is there a way i can create a hyperlink inside the `<p>` wihout using `<a>` after the dom? Or should I use a `<span>` that changes into a link? and how?

Thanks for any advice you can give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have nested `a` tags. Not only is it invalid HTML, but it has no way of actually working.

If you need the internal `a` to be a hyperlink, make sure the jQuery trigger object is another type of element, such as a `div` or `span` - both of which you can add click events to.

Comment: You can nest img tag to a tag

Comment: That's not nested `a` tags then.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct.
I used this in my lightbox 
<span class="link" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'">google.com</span>
but unwraped the span in the thumbnail like this: $('.elementOver span.link').contents().unwrap();

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/VvPtu/

```
jQuery('.elementOver p').append('<span onclick="anchor();">Hello world</span>');

function anchor() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.site.com/';
              }
```

Comment: this onclick is not working in fiddle but paste it in your html will work fine

Comment: Thanks so much but this would be the correct answer if the links wouldn't have to be dynamically.